# Any decent resources on how to map complex POCO objects in EF 4.1?

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities

So I heard L2S is going the way of the dodo bird. I am also finding out that if I use L2S, I will have to write multiple versions of the same code to target different schemas even if they vary slightly.  I originally chose L2S because it was reliable and easy to learn, while EF 3 wasn't ready for public consumption at the time.

After reading lots of praises for EF 4.1, I thought I would do a feasibility test. I discovered that EF 4.1 is a beast to get your head around. It is mindnumblingly complex with hundreds of ways of doing the same thing. It seems to work fine if you're planning on using simple table-to-object mapped entities, but complex POCO object mapping has been a real PITA.  There are no good tutorials and the few that exist are very rudimentary.

There are tons of blogs about learning the fundamentals about EF 4.1, but I have a feeling that they deliberately avoid advanced topics.  Are there any good tutorials on more complex mapping scenarios?  For instance, taking an existing POCO object and mapping it across several tables, or persisting a POCO object that is composed of other POCO objects?  I keep hearing this is possible, but haven't found any examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by EFv4.1? Do you mean overhyped code-first / fluent-API? In such case live with a fact that it is mostly for simple mapping scenarios. It offers more then L2S but still very little in terms of advanced mappings.

The basic mapping available in EF follows basic rule: one table = one entity. Entity can be single class or composition of the main class representing the entity itself and helper classes for set of mapped fields (complex types).

The most advanced features you will get with EF fluent-API or designer are:

- TPH inheritance - multiple tables in inheritance hierarchy mapped to the same table. Types are differed by special column called discriminator. Shared fields must be in parent class.
- TPT inheritance - each type mapped to the separate table = basic type has one table and each derived type has one table as well. Shared fields must be defined in base type and thus in base table. Relation between base and derived table is one-to-one. Derived entities span multiple tables.
- TPC inheritance - each class has separate table = shared fields must be defined in base type but each derived type has them in its own table.
- Entity splitting - entity is split into two or more tables which are related by one-to-one relation. All parts of entity must exist.
- Table splitting - table is split into two or more entities related with one-to-one relation.

Designer also offers

- Conditional mapping - this is not real mapping. It is only hardcoded filter on mapping level where you select one or more fields to restrict records which are allowed for loading.

When using basic or more advanced features table can participate only in one mapping.

All these mapping techniques follow very strict rules. Your classes and tables must follow these rules to make them work. That means you cannot take arbitrary POCO and map it to multiple tables without satisfying those rules.

These rules can be avoided only when using EDMX and advanced approach with advanced skills = no fluent API and no designer but manual modifications of XML defining EDMX. Once you go this way you can use

- Defining query - custom SQL query used to specify loading of new "entity". This is also approach natively used by EDMX and designer when mapping database view
- Query view - custom ESQL query used to specify new "entity" from already mapped entities. It is more usable for predefined projections because in contrast to defining query it has some limitations (for example aggregations are not allowed).

Both these features allow you defining classes combined from multiple tables. The disadvantage of both these mapping techniques is that mapped result is read only. You must use stored procedures for persisting changes when using these techniques.

Comment: Should I be using Nhibernate instead. Is its mapping scenarios more complex?

Comment: NHibernate offers better mapping features but yes the mapping can be more complex compared to fluent-API or designer in EF but more intuitive compared to manual maintaining of EDMX in EF without designer support.

Comment: As I mentioned, to Kamyar, EF 4 is not for me. I will stick to L2S.  Rather than use its simple mapping, I'll perform queries and massage them into my POCO objects, since they contain lots of agreggations that EF 4 doesn't handle.  Neither technologies, including NHibernate can map an object to a field, such as a comma delimited field.

Answer (score 2):

*Disclaimer: IMO EF 4.1 is best known for its Code-First approach. Most of the following links point to articles about doing stuff in code-first style. I'm not very familiar with DB-First or Model-First approaches.*

I have learned many things from [Mr. Manavi's blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/default.aspx). Especially, the [Inheritance with code-first series](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/24/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph.aspx) was full of new stuff for me. [This MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896343.aspx) has some valuable links/infos about different mapping scenarios too. Also, I have learned manu stuff by following or answering questions with `entity-framework` tags here on SO.

Whenever I want to try some new complex object mapping, I do my best (based on my knowledge about EF) to create the correct mappings; However sometimes, you face a dead end. That's why god created StackOverflow. :)

Comment: I went through a few of his videos and it was hard to understand what he was saying.  The blogs are better, but it's more of the same.  It is a real brain buster to read through it. I think I will continue to use Linq to Sql, since I can query the database using the generated entities and then massage it into my POCO objects.  There's also the case where sometimes, I need to map an object into a field, a scenario I'm sure EF can't handle.